# SQL how to limit number of a specific column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (books) like this:

```
id | author | book
--------------
1, Joy, book1
2, Joy, book2
3, Bob, book3
4, Bob, book4
5, Bob, book5
6, Dan, book6
...
```

I need a query to get 10 authors with their books. The below select is NOT what I want:

```
SELECT author, book
FROM books
LIMIT 10
```

How can I limit the result in 10 authors?

Comment: what database platform?

Comment: @OldProgrammer PostgreSQL

Comment: Do you care which 10 authors?

Comment: The query is with some conditions like 'WHERE id > 5', but not for specific authors.

Answer (score 5):

here is one way :

```
select * from (
   select * , dense_rank() over (order by author) rn
   from books
) t where t.rn < 11
```

Answer (score 0):

As a note:  If these are your only columns, then you might consider aggregation:

```
select author, array_agg(book)
from books
group by author
limit 10;
```

This returns 10 rows rather than a variable number of rows.